# Spring Tool Suite throwing XML errors on java source files

Tags: java, spring, spring-tool-suite

In Spring Tool Suite 3.6.3, I am getting the following error on a java source file:

```
!ENTRY org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core 1 0 2015-04-27 09:11:51.578
!MESSAGE Error occured processing '/project/package/Application.java'
!STACK 0
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

This happened after a refactoring to change the name to Application.java.

Is Application.java treated in some special way by Spring Tool Suite? Seems like it may be trying to generate an xml file (which is invisible to me) for this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug to be. Can you please open an issue at https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS and attach a sample project with a few steps how to reproduce this error? That would be great. Thanks a lot!!!